# How to specify ANY for tags in the yaml file for pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, build-pipeline, yaml, pipeline

In my pipeline definition, for getting resources from other pipeline, I'd like to define a default tags value to use, such as "release candidate", but allow to select to use any tags or even without tag. Is there a simple way to do so?

Here's my attempt but seems like "*" doesn't work:(

```
parameters:
- name: TagsToUse
  displayName: 'Select the tags to use for artifact from pipeline xxxx'
  type: string
  default: 'release candidate'
  values:
  - 'release candidate'
  - '*'

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: xxxx
    project: 'MyProject'
    source: 'TargetSource'
    branch: 'master'
    tags: ${{ parameters.TagsToUse }}
...
...
...
```

Comment: My gut feeling is you can't. Not everything in yaml pipelines is equal or interpreted the same way. You could try a [condition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditional-insertion) but I think it might not be valid `- ${{ if ne(parameters.tags, '*') }}:`

Comment: hum... thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `values:` is a way to restrict what can be passed into the parameters. For this reason, there isn't a way to wildcard an input value.

Since what you want to do is allow anything but default to 'release candidate' if nothing is provided, you really only need `default:` and can remove the `values:` restriction.